# Question about Lists and ArrayLists and more specifically about casting

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Why first three lines didn't compile and the remaining 2 did? How exactly does this work?

```
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //List<Number> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); DIDN'T compile
        //List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Number>(); DIDN'T compile
        //List<Object>nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();  DIDN'T compile
        //List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(); compiled
        //List<? super Number> nums = new  ArrayList<Object>(); compiled
    }
}`
```

Comment: The official Java tutorial explains this fairly well:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 3 line was not compiled because in Java, generic types are not satisfied or covariant fro ensuring type safety which means that `List<Intreger>` is not count a sub type of `List<Number>`. lets describe line of given code

**Don't Compile Line :**

- `List<Number> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();` : We can not assign a `List<Integer>` to a variable type of `List<Number>` because generics in java are not covariant.
- `List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Number>();` : Same reason as first one ,we can't assign `List<Number>` to a variable type of `List<Integer>`
- `List<Object>nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();` : Same reason as first one ,we can't assign `List<Integer>` to a variable type of `List<Object>`

**Compiled Line :**

- List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList(); : This line work because in this line you use a wildcard with a upper bound  `? extends Number`. Upper bound wildcard allows you to accept any subtype of type `T`. That mean  `? extends Number` this accept `Integer`, `Double`, `Float` etc.
- List<? super Number> nums = new  ArrayList(); :
- List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList(); : This line work because in this line you use a wildcard with a lower bound `? extends Number`.Lower bound wildcard allows you to accept any super type of type `T`.
  That mean  `? extends Number` this accept  `Number` and `Object`.